# Is there a Swift equivalent to GCC `__attribute__((constructor))`?

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble creating something in pure Swift. I'm trying to implement a registry of classes similar to NSValueTransformer.

In Objective-C, I'd ensure that the NSValueTransformer subclasses were registered by calling `setValueTransformer:forName:` in the `load` class method of the subclass. This approach doesn't work in Swift because the runtime doesn't call `load` on Swift classes.

My next idea was to find the Swift version of `__attribute__((constructor))` but my search came up blank. Does Swift provide something akin to `__attribute__((constructor))` or is the only way to achieve this to write a C function that calls a Swift function?

Comment: Have u found the solution for your question? I too have a similar need. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your registry of classes is wrapped in a bundle, then you can make use of bundle's principal class to find and register the transformers. If not, you can make use of `AppDelegate`'s app did finish launching method family to do it.

Either way, you'll need to search through all classes and register the ones you want. Objective-C has the nice `objc_getClassList()` to accomplish this, for Swift I found an interesting gist that adds this function to Swift: https://gist.github.com/bnickel/410a1bdc02f12fbd9b5e